# IBM Client Side SSO P8 Filenet Kerberos .Net C# Not Working

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, kerberos, filenet-p8

I am trying to get the SSO Kerberos example code from the info center for P8 Filenet working:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/sec_procedures.htm#sec_procedures__sec_procedures_kerberos

```
KerberosCredentials creds = new KerberosCredentials(); 
ClientContext.SetThreadCredentials(creds);  
IConnection conn = Factory.Connection.GetConnection(strURI); 
IDomain domain = Factory.Domain.GetInstance(conn, strP8Domain);
```

We are getting the following exception:

```
FNCRE0066: E_UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION
WSE594: InitializeSecurityContext call failed with the following error message: The network path was not found.
```

Searches have not produced much information.  The best lead I found was a reference to account "sc-service" not being configured correctly under our domain.  When I do setspn -L for my user id, it finds it no problem.  When I do the same for sc-service, it can't find it.

However, that post was 13+ years ago and I can't find any references saying that we need "sc-service" configured for Kerberos SSO to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your environment setup is like but here are a couple of pointers that might help:

- In a **cross-domain/realm Kerberos** setting, using shorter SPN is one of the reasons why the (network path not found) exception is thrown as the server name turns out to be ambiguous (through appearing in more than once in a forest, or if that shorter form is used with an external two-way trust or transitive two-way trust). If this is the case, try adding an '@' qualifier (e.g. FNCEWS/myce01@MYDOM.EXAMPLE.COM) to the SPN if you haven't already. Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.security.doc/p8psn035.htm
- For a **cluster-based Content Platform Engine**, no single SPN shall be mapped to more than one identity account, failure to ensure this would cause the exception. Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.security.doc/p8psn034.htm